# Code refactoring undefined method for #<Array:0x00559ec6b7d918>h

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, refactoring

I am trying to re-factor my code by creating method in my app. For instance, I have the following:

```
@clean_doc = @doc_broken_down_by_lines.reject { |a| a.split.size < 6 }
```

I want to put the

```
.reject { |a| a.split.size < 6 }
```

in a separate function

I tried to put

```
def remove_lines_with_less_than_6_words
  self.break_into_lines.reject { |a| a.split.size < 6 }
end
```

In many different different location including in the same controller or in an active record model and put

```
@clean_doc = @doc_broken_down_by_lines.remove_lines_with_less_than_6_words
```

but I get the error

```
undefined method `remove_lines_with_less_than_6_words' for #<Array:0x00559ec6b7d918>
```

Where should I put the code? Why do I get the error whereas the code appears identical? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where should I put the code?

You need to pass your array as a parameter to the method instead of using it as an instance method of `Array`:

```
def remove_lines_with_less_than_6_words(arr)
  arr.reject { |a| a.split.size < 6 }
end
```

And use it like this:

```
@clean_doc = remove_lines_with_less_than_6_words(@doc_broken_down_by_lines)
```

However, you can add the method in your controller (a private method) and use `@doc_broken_down_by_lines` without passing it as a parameter (since as an instance variable it will be available in all instance methods within the class):

```
private
def remove_lines_with_less_than_6_words
  @doc_broken_down_by_lines.reject { |a| a.split.size < 6 }
end
```

And use it like this:

```
@clean_doc = remove_lines_with_less_than_6_words
```

> Why do I get the error whereas the code appears identical?

It *appears identical*, but it is not identical at all. With *Ruby* you can call instance methods with `.`, so because `reject` is an instance method in `Array` class, you can call it with `my_array.reject`.

But once you create your own method, it is not being defined in `Array` class, thus it is not available as an instance method in `Array`, it is an instance method of the class where it is being defined (e.g. `MyController` or `MyModel` or wherever you decide to define that method).

So doing `my_array.my_custom_method` will result in the error you are getting:

> Undefined method `my_custom_method' for <#Array:...>